# Dojo -Stack Container - Ajax

Tags: ajax, dojo

How can I load Stack Container's content via ajax when clicked to controllers?

```
  <div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'">

            <div  id="#ddd"  data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.StackController" data-dojo-props="containerId:'contentStack'"></div>

        </div>


        <div  class="centerPanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.StackContainer" data-dojo-props="region: 'center',id: 'contentStack'">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title: 'Group 1'">
                <h4>Group 1 Content</h4>
                <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title: 'Group Two'">
                <h4>Group 2 Content</h4>
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title: 'Long Tab Label for this One'">
                <h4>Group 3 Content</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `href` attribute for the contained ContentPanes - see http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html#href

A jsfiddle to show how this is supposed to work: http://jsfiddle.net/NL623/